# Scrapy and MySQLdb

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, mysql-python

I'm using `Python 2.7` on `Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5`.

I originally had an issue with installing `MySQLdb` using both `pip-2.7 install MySQL-python` as well as downloading and then running `python2.7 setup.py build` and `python2.7 setup.py install`.  I tried these different methods using both 32 and 64 bit installs of `MySQL` and corresponding architectures, but to no avail.

My solution was to install `Macports`.  I then installed `MySQL` and `MySQL-python` (`MySQLdb`) using Macports.

I use `Wing IDE` for developing code, so I switched over to the Macports version of `Python` - importing `MySQLdb` works.  I also switched the default terminal version of Python to this Macports version and verified that it was the default by calling `python` from the command line- the correct version started.

So now the problem:  I'm using scrapy to scrape a movie web page for info.  My pipeline directs the scraped data to a database, which uses the previously mentioned `MySQLdb` module.  When I go to the command line, `cd` into my project and run `scrapy crawl MySpider`, I get the following error:

```
 raise ImportError, "Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)
 ImportError: Error loading object 'BoxOfficeMojo.pipelines.BoxofficemojoPipeline': No module named MySQLdb.cursors
```

I've checked and made sure that I can import MySQLdb.cursors from the python2.7 shell, so I think there is an issue with which version of Python scrapy is using...

:::::UPDATE:::::

Here is the full traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 131, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 76, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 138, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in run
spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/command.py", line 33, in crawler
self._crawler.configure()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 41, in configure
self.engine = ExecutionEngine(self, self._spider_closed)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 63, in __init__
self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 66, in __init__
self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 50, in from_crawler
return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 29, in from_settings
mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 39, in load_object
    raise ImportError, "Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)
    ImportError: Error loading object 'BoxOfficeMojo.pipelines.BoxofficemojoPipeline': No module named MySQLdb.cursors
```

:::::UPDATE 2:::::

Here is my current path:

```
 $PATH
  -bash:       /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python  .framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

::ALSO::

I added this to code in hopes of fixing things - it is the location of `py27-mysql` (`MySQLdb`), but the same error is returned:

```
 import sys; sys.path.append("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

::ALSO #2::

Here is the code for my pipeline- I have no idea whether or not it works, as I keep getting the error regarding the `import`, but thought it might be helpful:

```
 from scrapy import log
 from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
 import time
 import MySQLdb.cursors
 import sys; sys.path.append("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
 class BoxofficemojoPipeline(object):

     def __init__(self):
         print ('init')
         self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', db = 'testdb', user='testuser', passwd='test', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor, charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)



      def process_item(self, item, spider):
         print('process')
         query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)  #("""INSERT INTO Example_Movie (title, url, gross, release) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (item['title'].endcode('utf-8'), item['url'].encode('utf-8'), item['gross'].encode('utf-8'), item['release'].encode('utf-8')))
          query.addErrback(self.handle_error)#self.conn.commit()

         return item

      def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
         print ('conditional insert')
          #Create record if doesn't exist
          #all this block run on it's own thread

         tx.execute("select * from example_movie where url = %s", (item['url'], ))
         result = tx.fetchone()
         if result:
              log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level = log.DEBUG)
         else:
              tx.execute("insert into example_movie (title, url, gross, release) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (item['title'].encode('utf-8'), item['url'].encode('utf-8'), item['gross'].encode('utf-8'), item['release'].encode('utf-8')))
              log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" %  item, level=log.DEBUG)

      def handle_error(self, e):
         print ('handle_error')
         log.err(e)
```

Comment: Could you try to replace `import MySQLdb.cursors` with `import MySQLdb`?

Comment: @alecxe Thank you for taking the time to respond!  No, that didn't fix it- I'm almost certain it has something to do with the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who took the time to read and look at this. I found the problem after looking over the code one last time.  I realized that, in the code for my pipeline, the problem `import MySQLdb.cursors` comes before the `import sys; sys.path.append("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages")` (which is the location of the `MySQLdb module`).  Putting the `import sys; sys.path.append` statement before the `import MySQLdb` fixes the `import error` issue.